# GitHub workflow for reactjs website giving error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, workflow

I'm getting an error on GitHub workflow for my react js website which is hosted on firebase. When I run firebase deploy on my terminal it builds and deploys the site but it is not working for automatic deploys.

```
Run npm run build

> tool-frontend@1.0.0 build
> NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production

[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/home/runner/work/Tools-Website/Tools-Website/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'html-webpack-plugin'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/work/Tools-Website/Tools-Website/webpack.config.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/Tools-Website/Tools-Website/webpack.config.js:2:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) ***
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/runner/work/Tools-Website/Tools-Website/webpack.config.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
***
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When GitHub tries to build the repository it cannot find the "node modules" due to which we get this error. Therefore, in order to solve this you need to add an intermediate step to do `npm i` before you build.

Comment: You can refer to [this link](https://dev.to/chathula/how-to-set-up-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-a-node-js-app-with-github-actions-32h0) for more details.

Comment: I would suggest using `npm ci` as the command was made for things like Github workflows, as per [the npm docs.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci)